# Why the Range for in a two-dimensional Array is written in this way?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference

This is a tiny program from [github.com/pezy/CppPrimer](http://github.com/pezy/CppPrimer).

```
int ia[3][4] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};

// a range for to manage the iteration
for (const int(&p)[4] : ia)
    for (int q : p) cout << q << " ";
cout << endl;
```

Just want to know why here const int(&p)[4] is used in the range for.

I had intended to use `for(int p[4] : ia)`, because i thought in this way `p` will become a `int[4]` so it, whether by values or by reference, would work in the next line when each element in `p` is accessed by `q`.
But when I tried `for(int p[4] : ia)`, the compiler said cannot use `int*` to initialize a `int[]`. I just don't know why.

Furthure more, I know this code won't work:

```
int i = 10;
int *c= &i;
int &p = c;
```

A reference cannot be initialized by a pointer, but according to the error given by the compiler, it seems just the case in this range for.

Comment: The declaration `int(&p)[4]` declares `p` as a reference to an *array of four integers*. As it happens, `ia` is an array of three *arrays of four integers*..

Comment: @5gon12eder no it's not. If you're thinking about inner braces, they're optional :)

Comment: @Quentin Yes, I'm sorry. Confused C and C++.

Comment: Note that `int &p = c;` is wrong because you cannot assign a pointer to a reference, but you can dereference the pointer to get to the reference: `int &p = *c;` hth

Comment: BTW if you don't want to see the weird reference-to-array syntax, you can use automatic type deduction: `for (const auto& p : ia) ...`

Comment: @anatolyg Yes. But that's an exercise in  _C++ Primer_ which rules out the usage of 'auto'. I have known better that auto is really convenient and reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the range-for loop's mechanism (described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)), something equivalent to this happens :

```
int ia[3][4] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11};

// begin is deduced to be an int (*)[4]
auto begin = ia, end = ia + 12;

// Hence *begin is an int (&)[4]
int p[4] = *begin;
```

It is not possible, however, to copy-initialize an array from another array, and the code fails to compile.

The error message you get is because the compiler tries to decay `*begin` (a reference to a row) to a pointer to the first element of the row, which fails for the same reason.

The working example, however, ends up with :

```
const int (&p)[4] = *begin;
```

Which initializes a reference with another reference of the same type, with a `const` added. Which is perfectly valid.

Comment: Thanks. It's really helphul. I have just read the first four chapter of _C++ Primer_. It should be a quite long time before I am able to understand the mechanism of copy assignments and the like.

Answer (score 3):

```
for(int p[4] : ia)
```

Will try to copy the arrays. That's not allowed in C++.

```
for(const int(&p)[4] : ia)
```

uses a reference to iterate the arrays and does not copy their elements. And to the second code snippet:

```
int &p = c;
```

`p` is a **reference to `int`**, it cannot refer to a **pointer to `int`**. The following is valid:

```
int *&p = c; // reference to c
int &r = *c; // reference to int pointed to by c
```

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful.